# React-Native: Parsing Simple JSON GET/POST and Refresh every X Seconds

Tags: json, react-native, polling

Get data from JSON Response and populate a  field and refresh every X Seconds. It doesn't have to be a background task, just while the screen is active.

The responses would be:  res.name and res.host. It would also load the current image: res.imgurl

I have tried the code below, but the examples on the react site are quite complex and use lists, I just have simple JSON data, no array.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  fetch("https://broadcast.truthnetwork.com/play-currentshow.lasso?station=WTRU")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Server response :- \n", res);
  })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error from server :- \n", error);

  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.sometext}>Show Name:</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { 
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#375963',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sometext: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
});
```

Here is a sample JSON Response:

```
{
"name": "Encouraging Word", 
"imgurl": "https://broadcast.truthnetwork.com/_img/shows300/4B0FA4EA116331D9A1WH3AE062F0.jpg", 
"description": "This is a simple description", 
"slug": "encouraging-word-don-wilton", 
"weburl": "http://www.theencouragingword.org/", 
"feedurl": "http://feeds.feedburner.com/tewfbs", 
"host": "Don Wilton", 
"showid": "69"
}
```

I expect app to pull JSON and show the current show, show image and show host and refresh the data every 15-30 seconds (no background task is necessary, just while the screen is active).

Note: This API will work with GET OR POST on station=WTRU

Comment: How about `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach might come in handy. The following example fetches data from an API every 5 seconds using JavaScript's `setInterval`. We are making the request once the component first renders, in the `componentDidMount` method and removing the interval once the component **unmounts** inside `componentWillUnmount`.

You need to use **state** manipulation to update your screen after each api request after every x seconds. Since each state update causes a re-render.

**Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-pine-81hx4?fontsize=14**

Read more about `setInterval` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: {}
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getData();
    }, 5000);
  }

  getData = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({ data: json })
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.state.data.title}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```